# how i can hide the app icon in flutter after install

Tags: flutter

I've seen that there are some GPS or system application on Google apps where, after installation, the application will have no icon display .

i want hide app after permanently after installation in flutter

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Don't think to do.

**Android:**

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps#getActivityList(java.lang.String,%20android.os.UserHandle)), as of Android Q (API 29) all app icons will be visible in the launcher no matter what unless:

As of Android Q, at least one of the app's activities or synthesized activities appears in the returned list unless the app satisfies at least one of the following conditions:

The app is a system app.
The app doesn't request any permissions.
The tag in the app's manifest doesn't contain any child elements that represent app components.
Additionally, the system hides synthesized activities for some or all apps in the following enterprise-related cases:

If the device is a fully managed device, no synthesized activities for any app appear in the returned list.
If the current user has a work profile, no synthesized activities for the user's work apps appear in the returned list.

**iOS:**

This can be done, and it does not require jailbreaking.

It is, however, something that Apple would reject in their App Store. Please, however, do not equate what is not allowable in the App Store with what requires jailbreaking. Those are not the same thing. There are many "private" or "undocumented" features you may want to use in a hobbyist or enterprise app that doesn't get distributed through the App Store.

To hide an app's icon on the SpringBoard, add this to your Info.plist file:

SBAppTags
  
     hidden